# static varibale cant be changed from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

in the below code, I create the class FMSHandler to process a string value passed to it from the main method as follwos

```
while (true) {
        fmsHandler.process("param1_" + (++cnt) + ", param2_" + (cnt));
    }
```

what i want to do is, to allow the processing to be performed every 3 seconds. or in other words, every 3 seconds i read the message passed from the main throught the previously mentioned code and perform 
further processing. to do so, i created a static boolean variable called sIsProcessing to regulate the processing. this static variable is initially false and as long as there is 
a message being processed it will be true and it will be set back to false when the thread the performs processing finihes as shown in the code below.

the problem i am facing is, despite the while-loop runs for ever, the processing is applied once and it is NOT repeated every 3 seconds as i expected it.

please have alook at the code and let me know where is the mistake

**main**:

```
public class Main {

private final static String TAG = Main.class.getSimpleName(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FMSHandler fmsHandler = new FMSHandler();
    long startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();
    int cnt = 0;

    while (true) {
        fmsHandler.process("param1_" + (++cnt) + ", param2_" + (cnt));
    }
}
```

}

**FMSHandler** :

```
public class FMSHandler {
private final static String TAG = FMSHandler.class.getSimpleName();
private static boolean sIsProcessing = false;
private static int sCnt = 0;

public void process(String fmsMsg) {

    if (!sIsProcessing) {
        sIsProcessing = true;
        Log.w(TAG, "FMSHandler", "new task to be processed");
        new HandlerThread(HandlerThread.class.getSimpleName() + "_" + (FMSHandler.sCnt++), fmsMsg).start();
    }

}

class HandlerThread extends Thread {
    private String[] mSplittedFMS = null;
    private String mThreadName = "";

    public HandlerThread(String threadName, String fmsMsg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setName(threadName);
        this.mSplittedFMS = this.toArray(fmsMsg);
    }

    private String[] toArray(String fmsMsg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return fmsMsg.split(",");
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.w(TAG, "HandlerThread.run()", this.getName() + " started");

        for (int i = 0; i < this.mSplittedFMS.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "HandlerThread.run()", "this.mSplittedFMS: " + this.mSplittedFMS[i]);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "HandlerThread.run()", this.getName() + " finished");
        sIsProcessing = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the `sIsProcessing` variable as `volatile` or use an `AtomicBoolean`.

Also, currently, a lot of the messages passed to `process(...)` will be skipped, I'm not sure if that is your intention.

If you want to prevent messages from being skipped you will need to use synchronization to block the loop from the main thread while a message is being processed.

My suggestion will be to completely rewrite this and use a `Timer` and some kind of queue from the `concurrency` package like `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Here is an example:

```
public static final ArrayBlockingQueue<String> messages = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
public static final AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
.....
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        while(keepRunning.get()){
            String message = messages.take();// blocks until a message is avaiable
            synchronized(Thread.currentThread()){
                Thread.currentThread().wait(3000);// pause 3 seconds before starting to process the next message.
            }
        }
    }
}).start();

// add messages from some other class;
MessagesProcessor.messages.add("some message");
```

Comment: thnaks for your answer, would you mind to clarify how the synchronize block would prevent skipping message

Comment: is the MessagesProcessor.messages.add("some message"); should be called from the main inside the while-loop? sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @user2121 It will prevent skipping messages because it is not possible for multiple threads to get a lock on the same object. When a thread synchronize on an object, all the other threads that try to get that object's lock will block until the lock is released by the first thread.

Comment: Yes, you can call it from the loop in the `main` method but you will run into trouble very fast because in my example I've set the queue's capacity to 100 and giving the rate in which the messages are produced and consumed, the queue's capacity will be surpassed very fast.